# Upgrade to El Capitan?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I'm on Yosemite at the moment I want to upgrade but I fear it will break my applications. I have a MacBook Pro (Late 2011) 15''. The last time I updated my Logic Pro 8 broke and I was forced to pay $200 for Logic Pro X (it is my theory that Apple did that on purpose) but either way, what is your suggestion on the Operating System nonsense?

Comment: My suggestion would be that **you** look at the versions of software you have and then check with their manufacture if there are compatibility issues with OS X 10.11 and upgrade accordingly.

Comment: I think that people are way too cautious over updating. My Mid-2009 MacBook Pro runs just as well, if not better on El Capitan than on Yosemite. In fact, that's really what El Capitan is all about: performance, not new just new features. That said, I'm not sure about compatibility on every app that you have, but you can probably find that info on the developer's website.

Comment: Too cautious? OP said he lost a $200 piece of software. Seems right to ask his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t heard of any apps that work in 10.10 and don’t work in 10.11. Certainly not mainstream apps. [Roaringapps.com](http://roaringapps.com/apps?platform=osx&os=el-capitan&status=%C3%97) shows no applications with a “doesn’t work” for 10.11